# Problema dataTable e tabelas criadas dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

Boa tarde Galera,

Estou com problema ao usar o `dataTable()` em uma tabela criada dinamicamente.

no `HTML` eu tenho o corpo da tabela.

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="mytable">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Módulo</th>
    <th>Quantidade OP</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Quantidade</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>NF</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabela_full" class="text-center">
</tbody>
</table>
```

E no `.JS` eu acrescento as `<tr`> e as `<td>`

Aí vem o problema, como eu acrescento as linhas e colunas após o `DOM` ser criado?

```
$("#mytable").dataTable({paging: false});
```

não reconhece as linhas e colunas da tabela.

Alguém pode me ajudar? muito obrigado.

Comment: Qual função está usando para inserir as linhas ?

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função com esse seu código *js* e chame ela quando a pagina toda for carregada.

**Como fazer:**

No body inclua o atributo onload, desta maneira:

```
<body onload = "suaFunçãoDeCriarTabela()">
```

Dentro do *< script >* inclua isso:

```
function suaFunçãoDeCriarTabela(){

   //Seu código aqui (Só será iniciado quando a pagina estiver carregada)
}
```

Assim adicionará itens à tabela só quando a pagina inteira for carregada

Comment: <body onload = "showAlltable()">  está apresentando erro de Uncaught ReferenceError: showAlltable is not defined, mas no meu arquivo js a função já está criada

Comment: Edite sua pergunta adicionando o código da função "showAlltable()". Pode haver algum erro nele.

Comment: Seu código *js* está na Head ou dentro do Body?

Comment: Ele está no head

Answer (score 0):

Sei que já faz tempo, mas talvez isso ainda seja útil para alguém:

Pelo que entendi, a sua `$("#mytable").dataTable({paging: false});` não reconhece as novas linhas incluídas - é desta forma que precisa ser mesmo. Quando vc trabalha com Data Table as alterações são feitas de forma semelhante a um "DataSet", ou seja: vc faz uma cópia dos dados, altera o que precisa nesta cópia e depois salva as suas alterações na tabela definitiva.
Para incluir novas linhas a maneira mais fácil é utilizar um objeto que contenha **um atributo para cada coluna da sua tabela**. Além disso , sempre que vc adiciona novas linhas será necessário redesenhar a tabela (utilizando o ".draw()" - [dataTable.draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())) para que os dados novos sejam renderizados e apareçam na tela.

Exemplo:
Considere uma tabela chamada "myTable" com os campos nome, cpf e estadoCivil. Desta forma crie um objeto cliente com estes atributos:

[image: modelo objeto cliente]

Para adicionar este objeto na data table temos que utilizar uma função semelhante a esta:

```js
function addRowsDataTable(cliente){
//criando o "data set" - captura todos os dados da DataTable original e inclui eles na variavel dTable (é um array de objetos)
    dTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
  //incluindo o objeto cliente
  dTable.rows.add( 
            [{
                "nome"              : cliente.nome,                 //0
                "cpf"               : cliente.cpf,              //2
                "estadoCivil"   : cliente.estadoCivil
       }]
  );
    //renderizando novamente a dataTable com os novos dados.
    dTable.draw();  
}
```

**OBS: lembre-se de que na sua página HTML é necessário incluir as referências da data table:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>
```

e também:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/DataTables/datatables.css">
```

Como fazer?
Chame a função ***addRowsDataTable***  e passe como parâmetro um objeto ***cliente*** com os ***atributos necessários***. A função vai adicionar uma linha com os dados do cliente e renderizar novamente a tabela.